# How to apply custom css to ionic 4 components?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic4, shadow-dom

I am often running into the problem of not knowing what css to change for ionic components. For example I have a button that I am outlining using ionic, my initial guess was to overwrite its outline/border color with something like.

```
border: 1.2px solid #697954;
```

But that didnt work so I essentially just had to dig through forum posts until I found that its changed with

```
--border-color
```

This seems like an incredibly inefficient method to finding how to overwrite ionic component css variables.

Where can I find exactly what css ionic is using for its components so I can easily overwrite them without digging through forum posts? I checked in the ionic core.css on github, but that didnt give me the info I wanted.

Well know I have border color done correctly, but I need change the onclick background color and the onclick text color. I dont want to dig through the forums again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic 4 custom styling Shadow DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57477139/ionic-4-custom-styling-shadow-dom)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Ionic 4 component views are encapsulated in a shadow dom and therefore not designed to be easily overwritten with css. Each component has it's own documentation for how you can override common css properties, such as:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/button#css-custom-properties

There are a number of guides available for more information about styling shadow doms, such as:
https://www.joshmorony.com/styling-a-shadow-dom-in-ionic-4/

A similar discussion with the example applied to a button can be found here:
[Ionic 4 custom styling Shadow DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57477139/ionic-4-custom-styling-shadow-dom)

In some situations the Ionic Documentation isn't always up-to-date with the latest CSS variables that are available for a component. A sure-fire way to find out what variables are available is by looking at the master source code on Github for the component's CSS.

For example, if I wanted to see what variables are available for the `ion-range` component I would look at the [range.md.scss file](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/components/range/range.md.scss):

```
:host {
  --knob-border-radius: 50%;
  --knob-background: var(--bar-background-active);
  --knob-box-shadow: none;
  --knob-size: 18px;
  --bar-height: #{$range-md-bar-height};
  --bar-background: #{ion-color(primary, base, 0.26)};
  --bar-background-active: #{ion-color(primary, base)};
  --bar-border-radius: 0;
  --height: #{$range-md-slider-height};
  --pin-background: #{ion-color(primary, base)};
  --pin-color: #{ion-color(primary, contrast)};

  @include padding($range-md-padding-vertical, $range-md-padding-horizontal);

  font-size: $range-md-pin-font-size;
}
```

Here we can see all the variables available for the host component (in this case, `ion-range`).

Comment: Thank you! This was a very thorough answer to my question. I was afraid of not being able to find up to date stuff in the documentation, so the knowledge that its all on github will save me some headaches in the future.